# A basis $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ of Polynomial space of degree $2$, such that $[t^2]$ of the basis is $(1, 1, 0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

The only basis that I know of in $P_2$ is ${1, t, t^2}$, however that would not yeild $(1, 1, 0)$ for $t^2$, instead it would be $(0, 0, 1)$. How can I come up with this basis, so that for $t^2$ I would get $(1, 1, 0)$?

Comment: Well, just take $\;(1,t, t(t-1))$.

Comment: @Bernard, don't you mean $\{ t(t-1), t, 1 \}$?

Comment: t^2 of that basis would be (0, 0, 0), would it not? I need it to be (1, 1, 0).

Comment: @Justine: You're right. Mechanically, I sorted the polynomials by increasing degree.

Comment: @uRockNinja: $t^2=\color{red}1\cdot t(t-1)+\color{red}1\cdot t+\color{red}0\cdot 1$.

Comment: @Bernard I get that t2=1⋅t(t−1)+1⋅t+0⋅1t2=1⋅t(t−1)+1⋅t+0⋅1 but I'm thinking of it more in a vector form. In this basis, component 1 would correspond to t(t-1), component 2 : t, and component 3 : 1. Doesn't the second component have to have a t^2 in it for there to be a 1 in the second component of the vector?

Comment: No: it's there to annihilate the $-t$ that results from the expansion of $t(t-1)t$.

Answer (score 0):

We want (1): $\ t^2=p_1+p_2$.

We have many possibilities for choosing such a basis $p_1,p_2,p_3$.

Probably the easiest is if we take $p_1:=t^2-t$ and $p_2:=t$. 
This certainly satisfies (1), which already ensures that $t^2$ is in the span of $p_1,p_2(,p_3)$. 
Taking $p_3:=1$, we see that all standard basis elements, hence all polynomials of degree $\le2$, are generated by $p_1,p_2,p_3$, so it is a basis of this $3$ dimensional space.